# How can I resolve these errors when building a cocos2d app under Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

My app compiled fine before, but I'm now seeing the following errors when building with Xcode 4.2:

In GLES-Render.mm it is reporting:

```
variable length array of non pod element type b2vec2
```

and

```
`cannot initialize parameter of type CCScene with an rvalue of type helloworld`
```

I have used this code successfully for over a year without problem, so I'm guessing that I need to fix something in my build settings.  What can I do to resolve these errors?

Comment: you should also post the code that generates these errors

Comment: It would be worth to see the code where you are getting the errors.  Sounds like some parameters changed or maybe just some type casts that are necessary.  Tough to say without seeing the code though.

Comment: I have this error too, without even having any code related to Box2D in my game.

Comment: did my answer helped you with this?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
b2Vec2 vertices[vertexCount];
for( int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++) {
    vertices[i] = old_vertices[i];
    vertices[i] *= mRatio;
}
```

to:

```
ccVertex2F vertices[vertexCount];
for( int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++) {
    b2Vec2 tmp = old_vertices[i];
    tmp *= mRatio;
    vertices[i].x = tmp.x;
    vertices[i].y = tmp.y;
}
```